# Python regex to find "document" word in a given string in forward direction and replace by empty string

Tags: python, regex

If the word "document" can be produced by removing characters from a given string, the letters spelling "document" are to be removed from the string. If letters from the resulting string can be removed to leave the string "document", the letters spelling "document" in that string are removed. This continues until letters cannot be removed to leave "document", at which time the final string is to be returned.

For example, if the string were:

```
documdocumententer
     ^^^^^^^^
```

"document" can be formed by removing "docum" from the beginning and "enter" at the "end", so "document" in the middle is removed, leaving

```
documenter
^^^^^^^^
```

The process would then be repeated to leave

```
er
```

As "er" does not contain "document", "er" would be returned.

Similarly, if the string were:

```
adbocucdmefgnhtj
 ^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^
```

the letters spelling "document" would be removed to leave:

```
abcdfghj
```

This string would be returned because it does not contain "document".

**Examples**

1. **`doconeument`** is converted to **`one`**
2. **`documdocumentent`** is converted to an **`empty string`**
3. **`documentone`** is converted to **`one`**
4. **`pydocdbument`** is converted to **`pydb`**
5. **`documentdocument`** is converted to an **`empty string`**

How can I obtain the string of interest from a given string (for the specific word "document" only).

i tried this query by python for loop, but i didn't get idea how to do with only regex
my code is below

```
import re
def fun1(text):
    print('original string:', text)
    pattern = r"((d|D).*o.*c.*u.*m.*e.*n.*t){1,}"
    result = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
    if len(result) == len(text):
        print('return original string because it does not contain "document" word forward direction:')
        return text

    # if word is containing "document" in forward direction

    temp = []   # for storing letter and its index

    # find each letter and index in "document" word
    search_str = 'document'
    for index in range(len(search_str)):
        # if it is a last letter in "document" that is t
        if index == len(search_str)-1:
            current_letter = search_str[index]
            pattern = r'.*n.*t'

        else:
            next_letter = search_str[index + 1]
            current_letter = search_str[index]
            pattern = rf".*{current_letter}.*{next_letter}"

        result = re.match(pattern, text)
        a, b = result.span()
        if temp:
            # value of last dict in temp list
            val = list(temp[-1].values())[0]
            current_letter = val + text[val:].index(current_letter)
        else:
            # first time when temp list is empty
            current_letter = text[a:b].rindex(current_letter)

        temp.append({search_str[index]: current_letter})

    # now using temp list we remove "document" word at specific index
    text = list(text)

    # create a list with index decending order to remove from text
    remove_index_list = [list(i.values())[0] for i in temp]
    remove_index_list.sort(reverse=True)

    for j in remove_index_list:
        text.pop(j)

    final_txt = ''.join(text)
    # to check if text containing or not one more "document" word
    pattern = r"((d|D).*o.*c.*u.*m.*e.*n.*t){1,}"
    result = re.findall(pattern, final_txt)
    if result:
        print('The word again containing "document" in it')
        final_txt = fun1(final_txt)
    return final_txt
print('final_output:', fun1('doconeument'))
```

Comment: What should be the output of dadocument - da or ad?

Comment: @DavidWierichs da

Answer (score 8):

I have a solution with regular expressions and recursion:

```
from re import compile

candidates = ["doconeument", "documdocumentent",  "documentone",
              "pydocdbument", "documentdocument", "hansi"]
word = "document"

def strip_word(word, candidate):
    regex = compile("^(.*)" + "(.*)".join(word) + "(.*)$")
    match = regex.match(candidate)
    if not match:
        return candidate
    return strip_word(word, "".join(match.groups()))

for cand in candidates:
    print(f"'{cand}' -> '{strip_word(word, cand)}'")
```

Edit: Did a correction on the code (two first lines of function were left outside).

Comment: Please note my edit ... without it, the `word` was hardcoded. Now it should work with variable words.

Comment: I'm so puzzled by this, I'd give it more than one upvote if I could. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

If the given string fails to match the regular expression:

```
r'^([a-z]*)d([a-z]*)o([a-z]*)c([a-z]*)u([a-z]*)m([a-z]*)e([a-z]*)n([a-z]*)t([a-z]*)$'
```

the string is returned. If the regex matches the string, the string:

```
"\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9"
```

is formed and an attempt is made to match that string with the regex. This process is repeated until there is no match, at which time the last string tested is returned. Note that each string thus produced contains 8 characters fewer than the preceding string.

[Demo, step 1](https://regex101.com/r/7N0EiV/2/)

[Demo, step 2](https://regex101.com/r/7N0EiV/3/)

If the regex matches the string, capture group 1 will contain the substring that precedes "d" in "document", capture group 2 will contain the substring that is between "d" and "o", and so on, with capture group 9 containing the substring that follows "t". Some or all of these substrings may be empty.

I will leave it to the OP to produce the Python code needed to implement this algorithm.

Comment: thanx for ans and describe my query in question perfectly