# java - how many times char of string can get input inside another string

Tags: java, string, count

I need to count how many times one string can be inside another string.
Like if I have `String one = "eloloel"`, `String two = "elo"` , so it can be

1. `**elo**loel`
2. `**e****l**ol**o**el`
3. `**e**lo**l****o**el`

if you can help with this problem please

Comment: It would be great if you can paste here what program you have already written and then where are you getting stuck?

Comment: This similar question may help, though it is for Python rather than Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108354/python-regex-to-find-document-word-in-a-given-string-in-forward-direction-and

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `substring(int begIndex, int endIndex)` inside `for-loop` that goes from 0 to `length()`. I am not sure though.

Comment: i found this exact code.                                                                                                                                               
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   for (int j = i+1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
         System.out.println(str.substring(i,j));

Answer (score 0):

found if someone need it :P
amm only need to make it recursion now if someone wan help :P hhh

```
public static int howmany(String word, String pattern) {
      int count = 0;
      int strLen = word.length();
      int patLen = pattern.length();
      for(int i = 1;i<=pattern.length();i++){
          for(int j = 1;j<=word.length();j++){
           if(str.charAt(strLen-j)==pattern.charAt(patLen-i)){
                 count++;
            }
           }
      }                       
      return count;
}
```